# Programmatically get screen size in Mac OS X

Tags: cocoa, macos, screen, resolution

I am able to return the screen size using:

```
- (void) getScreenResolution {

    NSArray *screenArray = [NSScreen screens];
    NSScreen *mainScreen = [NSScreen mainScreen];
    unsigned screenCount = [screenArray count];
    unsigned index  = 0;

    for (index; index < screenCount; index++)
    {
      NSScreen *screen = [screenArray objectAtIndex: index];
      NSRect screenRect = [screen visibleFrame];
      NSString *mString = ((mainScreen == screen) ? @"Main" : @"not-main");

      NSLog(@"Screen #%d (%@) Frame: %@", index, mString, NSStringFromRect(screenRect));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> Screen #0 (Main) Frame: {{0, 4}, {1344, 814}}

Is there a way to format `{1344, 814}` to **`1344x814`**?

---

### Edit:

This works perfectly:

```
- (NSString*) screenResolution {

    NSRect screenRect;
    NSArray *screenArray = [NSScreen screens];
    unsigned screenCount = [screenArray count];
    unsigned index  = 0;

    for (index; index < screenCount; index++)
    {
        NSScreen *screen = [screenArray objectAtIndex: index];
        screenRect = [screen visibleFrame];
    }

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1fx%.1f",screenRect.size.width, screenRect.size.height];
}
```

Comment: I suggest using fast enumeration instead of indexes for the loop. It will make it both faster and easier to read. Also, `visibleFrame` is not the same thing as `frame`; `visibleFrame` excludes the region occupied by the Dock or (when the Dock is hidden) the show-Dock trigger region, plus the menu bar.

Comment: Your code may be much more simple. First of all `for (NSScreen *screen in [NSScreen screens])`.

Comment: Is there a way to get the screen size in real-life measurements? That is, in centimeters or inches?

Comment: You will need to covert pixels to whatever you want. Should be easy enough. Just use the method above to get pixels, then covert.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`NSLog(@"%fx%f",screenRect.size.width, screenRect.size.height);`

Comment: Sweet, `return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0fx%.0f",screenRect.size.width, screenRect.size.height];` worked perfectly to return **1024x768**, thanks.

Answer (score 27):

In Swift 4.0 you can get the screen size of the main screen:

```
if let screen = NSScreen.main {
    let rect = screen.frame
    let height = rect.size.height
    let width = rect.size.width
}
```

If you look for the size of the screen with a particular existing window you can get it with:

```
var window: NSWindow = ... //The Window laying on the desired screen
var screen = window.screen!
var rect = screen.frame
var height = rect.size.height
var width = rect.size.width
```

Answer (score 20):

Finding the screen size in Mac OS is very simple:

```
NSRect e = [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame];
H = (int)e.size.height;
W = (int)e.size.width;
```

Comment: Why are you casting the width and height to `int`s?

Comment: @PeterHosey Probably to indicate the height and width _are_ `int`s :)

Comment: @tomsmeding: Members of `NSRect`, `NSPoint`, and `NSSize` are `CGPoint`s.

Answer (score 11):

edit/update

**Swift 4**

```
NSScreen.main?.frame         // {x 0 y 0 w 1,920 h 1,200}
NSScreen.main?.frame.width   // 1,920.0
NSScreen.main?.frame.height  // 1,200.0
```

---

**Swift 3.x**

```
NSScreen.main()?.frame         // {x 0 y 0 w 1,920 h 1,200}
NSScreen.main()?.frame.width   // 1,920.0
NSScreen.main()?.frame.height  // 1,200.0
```

---

**Swift 2.x**

```
NSScreen.mainScreen()?.frame         // {x 0 y 0 w 1,920 h 1,200}
NSScreen.mainScreen()?.frame.width   // 1,920.0
NSScreen.mainScreen()?.frame.height  // 1,200.0
```

Comment: Check your screen resolution you are probably not using the maximum resolution

Comment: change it from "Default" to "More space"

Answer (score 7):

For those guy who are looking for a way to get screen resolution:

If you are programming a window based app, you can simply get the resolution from _window.screen.frame.size

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3 solution:**

`NSScreen.main()!.frame`