# OSX App: Get max resolution of the user's display (Swift)

Tags: macos, swift, resolution, screen-resolution, screen-size

I'm trying to get the max resolution of the user's display-- not necessarily the *current* resolution, but the maximum the display supports. I know that I can get the current resolution with something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982656/programmatically-get-screen-size-in-mac-os-x) but I need the maximum (ie: on a MBP 13inch the resolution would be 2560x1600).

I know I can do this in Terminal using something like [this](https://superuser.com/a/447298), but I would like to avoid trying to do something hack-y in the Terminal, and instead do it with Swift. Any suggestions on how I can do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Quartz Display Services.  First, get a list of the displays, probably with `CGGetActiveDisplayList`.  Then, for each display, use `CGDisplayCopyAllDisplayModes`.  Iterate over the array of modes, using `CGDisplayModeGetWidth` and `CGDisplayModeGetHeight` to figure out which is highest resolution.